# Wait for AJAX response in Selenium

Tags: python, ajax, selenium

I am trying to scrape a page, where depending on the button pressed `<div id="values"></div>` contains different content. I am using Selenium to click on the buttons and get afterwards the content of the `div`. Unfortunately, AJAX needs some time to get the data and the script runs too fast. For that I've added `time.sleep(3)` in my python script.
To be faster with scraping, I prefer to continue scraping immediately after the new content is loaded (depends on network speed).

I have already tried using `$.active` to detect when AJAX is ready, but it doesn't work.

```
try:
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(driver.execute_script("return $.active == 0"))
finally:
  values = driver.find_element_by_id("values")
```

What other ways are there to check if new element contains new data and then to continue?

Comment: selenium doc: [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what to do. In my case <div>Content#1</div> does already exist, so I can't check the existence of the <div> when checking if Check#2 was loaded

Comment: then check existence of `div` with text `Check#2` - probably `xpath('//div[@text="Check#2"]')` - or check existence of second `div` - ie. `xpath('//div[2]'`)